# How to create a voting system with AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery voting system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722874/jquery-voting-system)

I've been using [this tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/08/vote-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html) to create a voting system.

The problem is that on the tutorial the votes update because he can just echo out the votes into the same place if that makes sense. But what if I had an image triggering the vote and I wanted to then update the votes which were somewhere else on the page?

For example, his "button" to vote up holds the amount of votes up, but I want to hold that data somewhere else but don't know how to auto update it once the vote has been completed.

Also, my image always disappears when I click it, how can I stop that?

I would post the code, but it's basically the same as the tutorial only changed for my own needs.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722874/jquery-voting-system?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604953/ajax-php-voting-system?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860895/jquery-ajax-voting?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733283/up-or-down-voting-in-real-time-jquery-ajax-php?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you want to update the results in a new `<div id="new-results">`.
Using the same code inside the

```
$(".vote").click(function(){ /* his code here */ });
```

you'll want to replace

```
parent.html(html);
```

with

```
$("#new-results").html(html);
```

in both places where the parent is referred to.